# No module name bge

Tags: game-engine

I've downloaded upbge 0.30 from official website, but when I `import bge` I receive error Module error `no module named bge`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is "normal": you have to run your "game" by pressing "P" in layout mode.

Then it works.

The BGE lib isn't loaded at the start but only when starting your game.